# How to restore Spotlight user interface after killing it with Cocktail?

Tags: spotlight

I installed an App called cocktail and disabled spotlight. But now the Application does not start and it gives an error of some sort. I deleted the App and I do not have Spotlight anymore.

Can I enable it from some other place? How?

pastebin.com/Yw8czsFU

Comment: and how did you disable the Spotlight?

Comment: "an error of some sort" … knowing the error would help. Also, knowing whether it disabled indexing or just the UI

Comment: @Buscar웃 There was a menu item in the application I mentioned.

Comment: @Tetsujin I deleted the app so I do not know the error anymore. It only disabled the UI. CMD + Space does not work either.

Comment: Cocktail will only run if you have the correct version for the OS. Mavericks was v7, Yosemite is v8. It can disable UI &/or indexing, so we're not certain which you did, though after grgarside's answer it looks like UI

Comment: Please add within the OQ the output of the following command: `/usr/bin/sudo launchctl list`. This will help correct analysis.

Comment: @Buscar웃 It says operation already in progress.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Here: http://pastebin.com/Yw8czsFU

Comment: Clarify, do you see the spotlight in the menu bar,  do you have Spotlight in the system preferences? can you open it from there?

Comment: @Buscar웃 No, it is removed from the Menubar. The Magnifier icon is lost. CMD + Space does not work either. In System Preferences I see icon for Spotlight but it only opens preferences for Spotlight, not the search bar itself.

Comment: go here and get it /System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app

Comment: @Buscar웃 It says: -bash: /System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app: is a directory

Comment: @Buscar웃 When I try from Finder it says: The application “Spotlight.app” can’t be opened.

Comment: Please put the useful details requested within the original question. The comments fate is the trash.

Answer (score 1):

try

> `sudo chmod 755 /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search`

then

> `killall SystemUIServer`

Comment: ah, don't think that works in Yosemite. get the latest version of Cocktail instead & use that ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

Once running this, wait for Spotlight index to update.

Comment: I am getting: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist: Operation already in progress The software only disabled the UI I guess

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the status of spotlight on the boot volume?

```
mdutil -s /
```

If enabled, maybe you need to purge and rebuild. Just Try

```
sudo mdutil -Ei off /
```

This will disable Spotlight on the boot volume and delete the index. Then

```
sudo mdutil -i on /
```

This will re-enable Spotlight on the boot volume and create a new index.

Tail your log file to look for errors. For complete details, read the mdutil man page (`man mdutil`).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I removed coctail and installed again, then enabled spotlight.

Comment: thought that might turn out to be easiest ;)

Comment: so now we will never know how that happened :(

Comment: @Buscar웃 You can always install Cocktail, disable spotlight and remove Cocktail :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: or just disable it & check logs, see what it did

Comment: If you would like to make this question an interesting one, I would suggest to:
• uninstall Cocktail, • check that Spotlight UI is OK, • install Cocktail, • deactivate the Spotlight UI, • note and write here the "error message" you get.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest thing to do is go back to Cocktail >> System >> Spotlight >> Uncheck "Hide menu bar icon".